# Leer Excel con Java (Celdas sin rellenar)

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo un problema al leer un Excel, realmente tengo unos 10 Excels diferentes, y he hecho un código para leerlos todos.

El funcionamiento es el siguiente, voy leyendo celda a celda del Excel y el dato lo meto como tipo STRING en un array, cuando termina la función, envío el array a un método estático de la clase para crear el objeto.
Para crear el objeto lo que hago es cojo el número de columnas del Excel y divido el array entre eso.

Si me rellenan TODAS las celdas del Excel, el código funciona bien, el problema es cuando no me rellenan alguna celda, porque entonces el array sale de menos longitud y por tanto, no se puede crear bien el objeto.

Mi intención era crear algún tipo de case `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:`
Pero al no existir celda, puede saltar a `while (rowIterator.hasNext())` o al 
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

```
    //Array que devuelvo
    LinkedList<String> array = new LinkedList<String>();
    String stringValue = "";
    int cont = 0;

    try {

        InputStream inputStream = multipart.getInputStream();

        // Recojo el Excel
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet;
        Row row = null;
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = null;
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        // Si hay filas ->
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            // Guardo las filas y las celdas 
            row = rowIterator.next();
            cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            cont = 0;

            // Recorro cada celda  
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                // No me interesan las cabeceras.
                if (cell.getRowIndex() != 0) {
                    // Tipo de celda.
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                        // Este Excel y sus campos son especiales.
                        if (typeFile.equals("MAN-5") && cont == 6 || cont == 7 || cont == 13) {
                            stringValue = readDate(String.valueOf(cell.getDateCellValue()));
                        } else {
                            if (String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()).endsWith(".0")) {
                                stringValue = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                stringValue = stringValue.split("\\.")[0];
                            } else {
                                stringValue = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            }
                        }
                        // le pone un . a "2017."
                        if (cont == 0 || cont == 1) {
                            stringValue = removeDot(stringValue);
                        }
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        stringValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                    }
                    // Junto la columna 2 y 1 como un solo dato.
                    if (cont == 1) {
                        createPeriod(stringValue, array);
                    } else {
                        array.add(stringValue);
                    }

                }
                cont++;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        array = null;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Formato del Excel ->

```
AÑO  | MES | DATO1 | DATO2 | DATO3
2017    01    1        11      
2018    02             2
2018    03     1
```

Ahora creo el objeto en otro lado...

```
try {

            for (int y = 0; y < array.size(); y++) {
                if (y % 4 == 0) {
                    Article = new Article();

                    Article.setIdPeriod(array.get(y));
                    Article.setDato1(Double.parseDouble(array.get(y + 1).replace(',', '.')));
                    Article.setDato2(Double.parseDouble(array.get(y + 2).replace(',', '.')));
                    Article.setDato3(Double.parseDouble(array.get(y + 3).replace(',', '.'))); 

                    arrayArt.add(Article);

                }
            }
```

Explicaciones : 
Como el Excel tiene 5 columnas, y yo por código junto la 1º y la 2º, si vinieran todos los datos el Array es divisible entre 4 y tendría 1 objeto completo con todos los datos.

El problema que me acabo de encontrar es que sino me viene ALGÚN dato, el array se crea de esta forma -> `Array[201701][1][11][201802][2][201803][1]`

Si tuviera que dividir entre 4 partes este array, solo sale 1Objeto y medio y además setDato vale -> 201802, un completo desastre ....

Necesitaría saber que celda está vacía, pero no puedo, porque "no existe"
Por ejemplo para la fila 1 Dato3 no entra, hace directamente el

```
 while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
```

Gracias, espero que puedan ayudarme.

Pd: Estoy usando ->

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trabajando con una hoja de cálculo deberías seguir la misma filosofía que con una base de datos: tienes columnas y filas/registros que forman una tabla/hoja.

Lo normal en estos casos es usar una lista de mapas:

```
List<Map<String,String>> datos= new ArrayList<>();
```

y meter los datos con el nombre de la columna:

```
Map<String,String> fila= new HashMap<>();
fila.put("FECHA",anyo+mes);
fila.put("DATO1", ...);
```

De este modo es sencillo saber qué datos tienes y cuales son null/vacíos.

El mapa te da flexibilidad, pero también puedes crear un bean para cada fila y simplemente guardar una lista de beans:

```
class DatosExcel {

    private String fecha, dato1,dato2,dato3;

    //getters y setters
}
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, pero el problema sigue siendo el mismo, la "celda" dice que no existe porque no tiene datos y pasa al siguiente while, creo que con tu Map, pasaría lo mismo.

Comment: correcto, pero al leer el array sabes que cada elemento es una fila. La fila puede estar incompleta o no (fila.get("DATO3") devolvería null)

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo que he hecho ha sido pasarle el número de columnas y recorrer a mano celda a celda

```
private LinkedList<String> readToExcel(MultipartFile multipart, String typeFile) {

    LinkedList<String> array = new LinkedList<String>();
    int cont = 0;

    try {

        InputStream inputStream = multipart.getInputStream();

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet;
        Row row = null;
        int columns;

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            row = rowIterator.next();

            // Para no coger la cabeceras.
            if (cont == 0) {
                row = rowIterator.next();
            }

            cont = 0;

            switch (typeFile) {
            case "MAN-1":
                // Columnas del Excel.
                columns = 5;
                this.getCellType(row, columns, typeFile, array);
                break;
            case "MAN-2":
                columns = 3;
                this.getCellType(row, columns, typeFile, array);
                break;
            case "MAN-3":
                columns = 4;
                this.getCellType(row, columns, typeFile, array);
                break;
            case "MAN-4":
                columns = 4;
                this.getCellType(row, columns, typeFile, array);
                break;
            case "MAN-5":
                columns = 20;
                this.getCellType(row, columns, typeFile, array);
                break;
            case "MAN-6":
                columns = 4;
                this.getCellType(row, columns, typeFile, array);
                break;
            case "MAN-7":
                columns = 5;
                this.getCellType(row, columns, typeFile, array);
                break;
            }

            cont++;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        array = null;
    }
    return array;
}

// TODO: CAMBIAR LOS DEPRECATES
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private LinkedList<String> getCellType(Row row, int columns, String typeFile, LinkedList<String> array)
        throws ParseException {

    String stringValue = "";
    Cell cell;
    int cont = 0;

    do {
        cell = row.getCell(cont); // <--- Aquí voy acceder a la celda
        if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
            stringValue = ""; <--- Si la han dejado vacía.
        } else {
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (typeFile.equals("MAN-5") && cont == 6 || cont == 7 || cont == 13) {
                    stringValue = this.readDate(String.valueOf(cell.getDateCellValue()));
                } else {
                    if (String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()).endsWith(".0")) {
                        stringValue = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        stringValue = stringValue.split("\\.")[0];
                    } else {
                        stringValue = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                }
                if (cont == 0 || cont == 1) {
                    stringValue = removeDot(stringValue);
                }
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                stringValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (cont == 1) {
            createPeriod(stringValue, array);
        } else {
            array.add(stringValue);
        }

        columns--;
        cont++;

    } while (columns > 0);

    return array;
}
```

Con esto consigo acceder a las celdas a mano y sino metieron nada, le voy a poner a mi array un "" `Array -> [201701, , , dato3]` =)

Answer (score 0):

Tenía el mismo problema, pero después de intentar varias soluciones, lo resolví extrayendo los elementos sin hacer uso de la clase `java.util.Iterator`, y validando en la salida de cada celda si ésta es (nulo). En ese caso, añado un objeto de celda vacío de tal manera que relleno ese espacio de celda.
Les dejo el código que apliqué. Retorna un Vector de registros que internamente añade otro Vector para los datos, así vRegistros hace de (rows) y vDatos (cols).

LIBRERÍAS JAR UTILIZADAS:

- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- poi-3.7.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.7.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.7.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

EL CÓDIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE:

```
/*
* @author: MARCOS DEL PINO
* Fecha:   25-MAR-2022

*/

public class ExtraerDatosExcel {
    
    public ExtraerDatosExcel() {

    }
    
    public Vector obtenerDatosExcel(File fileName) {
        Vector vRegistro = new Vector();        
        try{
            int x = 0;
            List cellData = new ArrayList();
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet hssFSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
            for(int i=0;i< hssFSheet.getLastRowNum() ;i++){
                List cellTemp = new ArrayList();
                XSSFRow hssFRow = (XSSFRow) hssFSheet.getRow(i);
                for(int j=0;j< hssFRow.getLastCellNum();j++){
                    XSSFCell hssFCell = (XSSFCell)hssFRow.getCell(j);
                    if(hssFCell ==null){
                        hssFCell = hssFRow.createCell(j, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        //hssFCell.setCellValue("");
                    }else{
                        hssFCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    }
                    cellTemp.add(hssFCell);
                }
                //cuando el archivo describe en la primera row cabeceras de columnas
                if(x > 0){                
                    cellData.add(cellTemp);
                }
                x++;
            }
            vRegistro = obtener(cellData);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return vRegistro;
    }
    
    private Vector obtener(List cellDataList){
        Vector vRegistro = new Vector();
        for(int i=0; i<cellDataList.size(); i++){
            Vector vDatos = new Vector();
            vDatos.add(0, Integer.toString( (i+1) ));
            List cellTempList = (List) cellDataList.get(i);
            for(int j=0; j<cellTempList.size(); j++){
                XSSFCell hssFCell = (XSSFCell)cellTempList.get(j);
                hssFCell.setAsActiveCell();
                String stringCellValue = hssFCell.toString();
                vDatos.add((j+1), stringCellValue);
                System.out.println(stringCellValue + " ");
            }
            vRegistro.add(vDatos);
            System.out.println();
        }
        return vRegistro;
    }
    
    //ESTE ES EL EJEMPLO QUE USABA, PERO ME DABA EL PROBLEMA DEL TEMA EN MENCION
    private Vector obtenerDatosExcel_iterator(File fileName) {
        Vector vRegistro = new Vector();
        try{
            List cellData = new ArrayList();
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet hssFSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator rowIterator = hssFSheet.rowIterator();
            int x = 0;            
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
                XSSFRow hssFRow = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                Iterator iterator  = hssFRow.cellIterator();
                List cellTemp = new ArrayList();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    XSSFCell hssFCell = (XSSFCell)iterator.next();
                    hssFCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cellTemp.add(hssFCell);
                }
                if(x > 0){                
                    cellData.add(cellTemp);
                }
                x++;
            }
            vRegistro = obtener(cellData);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return vRegistro;
    }    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ls_path = "";
        Vector vRegistro = new Vector();
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("ARCHIVOS EXCEL", "xlsx", "xls");
        jfc.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            ls_path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
            File fileName = new File(ls_path);
            if(fileName.exists()){
                ExtraerDatosExcel miExcel = new ExtraerDatosExcel();
                vRegistro = miExcel.obtenerDatosExcel(fileName);
                vRegistro.toString();
            }
            System.out.println(ls_path);
        }        
    }
}
```